# Cordova phonegap finale convert to apk

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, apk

I created Simple cordova project using visual studio. I want ask
How to convert, save to apk? I tryed to run relise device, didnt
work, the file don't created. Should I use build.phonegap.com? Its
free?

Comment: Please provide more details. What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the android platform successfully you can easily use the cli to build the apk with the following command

```
cordova build android
```

you can even run the application in an emulator or device connected to your pc via the command

```
cordova run android
```

if you prefer to manually copy the apk to your device and then install from there, you can find the apk under **" \platforms\android\ant-build "**

Answer (score 1):

You can create the apk making a build using the cordova command line. You have to use this command inside your cordova app dir:

```
cordova build android
```

And after that look for you apk inside the android platform folder. Of course first you have to add the platform if you have not already done:

```
cordova platform add android
```

I hope this helps you!